# If I get a e14 to b22 converter, will this affect how bright the b22 bulb is? What about a gu10 to b22 converter?

Tags: lighting

I was buying same, and I suddenly wondered why they even have different kinds of light fitting. Is a e14 or gu10 socket capable of delivering enough juice to a b22 bulb? The old bulb was 9 watts, new one will be 15 watts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they should all have enough current capacity to handle 15 watts.

I don't need to ask your working voltage because at the lowest one likely (12V), current would only be 1.25 amps.  That's less than a turn signal bulb.

The light will be the same brightness.  If for some reason it is less brightness, that should be considered a serious threat, as that means the rest of the energy is trying to set something on fire.  In that case search for whatever's getting warm and fix it.

Comment: Ok. I looked at the circuit breaker and all the breakers are labeled 230v, including the ones with 'lights' handwritten on them. I always thought lighting circuits had a lower voltage but there you go.